# How to translate Timestamp to readable format? E.g. 1525344824207849500

Tags: web3js

How to translate Timestamp to something readable? E.g. 1525344824207849500

```
var blocknumber = web3.eth.blockNumber;
var blockHash = web3.eth.getBlock(blocknumber).hash;
var timestamp = web3.eth.getBlock(blocknumber).timestamp;
```

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is the unix time, ie number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00. And javascript's Date is the number of milliseconds since the same date. So something like this work

```
new Date(timestamp * 1000)
```